# How can I print a message box to a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Messagebox outputting the difference between two dates in minutes. I want to change this so that it prints the result in column "O" inline with the 'StartTime'.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()
    Dim Transmit As Boolean
    Dim StartTime As Date
    Dim EndTime As Date
    Dim RunTime As Date
    Dim messagebox As String
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0
    'conditions for startTime
    While Cells(i + 12, 1) = "Time"
        If (Cells(i + 12, 6) = " Active" And Cells(i + 12, 8) = " False" And Transmit = False) Then
            Transmit = True
            StartTime = CDate(Cells(i + 12, 2))
        End If

        'conditions for endTime
        If ((Cells(i + 12, 6) = " Standby" Or Cells(i + 12, 6) = " Shutdown" Or Cells(i + 12, 8) = " True") And Transmit = True) Then
            EndTime = Cells(i + 12, 2)
            Transmit = False         
        End If            

        If (Cells(i + 12, 6) = "Active" And Cells(i + 12, 8) = "True" And Transmit = False) Then

        Else

        End If

        If StartTime = 0 Or EndTime = 0 Then

        Else
            messagebox = MsgBox((DateDiff("n", StartTime, EndTime)), vbOKOnly)
            StartTime = 0
            EndTime = 0
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Currently it prints each result into a message box when I want it to print to the row of the StartTime. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of the message box just write it to your desired cell: `Cells(row, column).Value = DateDiff("n", StartTime, EndTime)` where replace `row` and `column` with your desired values. • Note that row counting variables must be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim i As Long`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ How would this work with multiple rows? also the row of the StartTimes is constantly changing as im working with many different CSV files that i import onto the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

It remembers the `StartTimeRow` in a variable and then uses it to output in that row later.

Also because you always use `i + 12` you can just start with `i = 12` and then just use `i` instead of `i + 12` everytime.

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()
    Dim Transmit As Boolean
    Dim StartTime As Date
    Dim EndTime As Date
    Dim RunTime As Date
    Dim messagebox As String
    Dim i As Long
    i = 12

    Dim StartTimeRow As Long

    'conditions for startTime
    While Cells(i, 1) = "Time"
        If (Cells(i, 6) = " Active" And Cells(i, 8) = " False" And Transmit = False) Then
            Transmit = True
            StartTime = CDate(Cells(i, 2))
            StartTimeRow = i '### Remember in which row start time was.
        End If

        'conditions for endTime
        If ((Cells(i, 6) = " Standby" Or Cells(i, 6) = " Shutdown" Or Cells(i, 8) = " True") And Transmit = True) Then
            EndTime = Cells(i, 2)
            Transmit = False         
        End If            

        If (Cells(i, 6) = "Active" And Cells(i, 8) = "True" And Transmit = False) Then

        Else

        End If

        If StartTime = 0 Or EndTime = 0 Then

        Else
            Cells(StartTimeRow, "O").Value = DateDiff("n", StartTime, EndTime)
            StartTime = 0
            EndTime = 0
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```